# OnScrollListener called repeatedly

Tags: android, listview, onscrolllistener

I have 2 listview controls that each display part of the data of a list.  They are oriented above and below each other in a UI fragment.  The data displayed is tire information for a car, so the top listview displays data for the front wheels and the lower listview displays data for the rear wheels (with a car image between them).  The listviews are configured so that the data list in each view mirrors the data in the other.  So the top line of the top list is of the same dataset as the bottom line in the bottom list.  When the user scrolls either list, the other list scrolls in a mirrored fashion.  This enables the user to scroll the data such that the data they are interested in is positioned directly above and below the car image (bottom row of top list, top row of bottom list)

To accomplish this, I'm responding to the OnScrollListener-OnScroll event on one listview, making position calculations and calling listview.setSelectionFromTop(position, sety) on the other listview to update its position.

This is working fine in Android 4.xx when I first released the app.  Now in Android 7 and higher, it appears that a race condition is occurring where setting the position on one listview is triggering an OnScroll on the other and things go bad from there in a never ending series of OnScroll events.

I've tried adding a flag on the OnScroll function so that it won't trigger if its inside an OnScroll call from the other listview.  This didn't work as it appears that the OnScroll events triggered from calling setSelectionFromTop are asynchronous so they occur outside the flagged area.

One thing I've noticed is that it appears that the sizes of the listviews is critical and that they both need to be the exact same size.  In the original layout (Android 4.x) I've set their layoutHeight=120dp to fix their size.  However, current android doesn't appear to respect the layoutHeight values and the resulting UI shows them as different sizes, this may be a key to the puzzle.

Here's the onScroll code for one of the listviews, the code for the other is the same, just replace lvTop with lvBottom

```
OnScrollListener lTop=new OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        if (fInBottomScrollListener)
            return;

        fInTopScrollListener=true;

        // Get position of this lv top
        View cTop = lvTop.getChildAt(0);
        View cBottom = lvBottom.getChildAt(0);
        if (cTop==null || cBottom==null) return;

        int topOffset = cTop.getTop();
        int itemHeight = cTop.getHeight();
        int firstVisPos = lvTop.getFirstVisiblePosition();

        int setposition = totalItemCount - (visibleItemCount - (topOffset!=0 ? 1:0)) - firstVisPos-1;
        int sety= -(itemHeight + (topOffset>0 ? 0:topOffset));

        lvBottom.setSelectionFromTop(setposition, sety);
        fInTopScrollListener=false;
    }
};
```

I see in the log, a continuing list of onScroll events, when running on Android 4.X this list stops after scrolling is complete, whereas on 7.x and greater, it continues and scrolling is basically frozen on both listviews until I refresh the fragment

Comment: I've found a workaround by making one of the listviews the master and the other scrolling in a mirrored fashion along with it.  If anyone knows of a way to prevent the setSelectionFromtop() function from generating an onScroll event on the other listbox, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your calculations for the position and offset are incorrect, so the 2 ListViews are bouncing beacuse of a small offset error.

For ListViews with same heights:

```
AbsListView.OnScrollListener lTop = new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        if (!fInBottomScrollListener) {
            fInTopScrollListener = true;
            View cTop = lvTop.getChildAt(visibleItemCount - 1);
            if (cTop == null) return;
            int setposition = totalItemCount - visibleItemCount - firstVisibleItem;
            int sety = view.getHeight() - cTop.getBottom();
            lvBottom.setSelectionFromTop(setposition, sety);
            fInTopScrollListener = false;
        }
    }
};

AbsListView.OnScrollListener lBottom = new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        if (!fInTopScrollListener) {
            fInBottomScrollListener = true;
            View cBottom = lvBottom.getChildAt(visibleItemCount - 1);
            if (cBottom == null) return;
            int setposition = totalItemCount - visibleItemCount - firstVisibleItem;
            int sety = view.getHeight() - cBottom.getBottom();
            lvTop.setSelectionFromTop(setposition, sety);
            fInBottomScrollListener = false;
        }
    }
};
```

Updated:

This is another approach, no matter the listviews' heights are same or not:

```
final private static int SCROLL_DELAY = 100;
long timestampScroll;

AbsListView.OnScrollListener lTop = new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        if (!fInBottomScrollListener) {
            fInTopScrollListener = true;
            View cTop = lvTop.getChildAt(0);
            View cBot = lvBottom.getChildAt(0);
            if (cTop == null || cBot == null) return;
            int lvTopMovableRange = (cTop.getHeight() + lvTop.getDividerHeight()) * totalItemCount
                    - lvTop.getDividerHeight() - lvTop.getHeight();
            int lvBotMovableRange = (cBot.getHeight() + lvBottom.getDividerHeight()) * totalItemCount
                    - lvBottom.getDividerHeight() - lvBottom.getHeight();
            int lvTopPointer = (cTop.getHeight() + lvTop.getDividerHeight()) * firstVisibleItem
                    - cTop.getTop();
            int lvBotPointer = (int)((float)(lvTopMovableRange - lvTopPointer)/lvTopMovableRange*lvBotMovableRange);
            int setposition = lvBotPointer / (cBot.getHeight() + lvBottom.getDividerHeight());
            int sety = -lvBotPointer + setposition * (cBot.getHeight() + lvBottom.getDividerHeight());
            timestampScroll = System.currentTimeMillis();
            lvBottom.setSelectionFromTop(setposition, sety);
            lvTop.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timestampScroll > (SCROLL_DELAY - 10)) fInTopScrollListener = false;
                }
            }, SCROLL_DELAY);
        }
    }
};

AbsListView.OnScrollListener lBottom = new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        if (!fInTopScrollListener) {
            fInBottomScrollListener = true;
            View cTop = lvTop.getChildAt(0);
            View cBot = lvBottom.getChildAt(0);
            if (cTop == null || cBot == null) return;
            int lvTopMovableRange = (cTop.getHeight() + lvTop.getDividerHeight()) * totalItemCount
                    - lvTop.getDividerHeight() - lvTop.getHeight();
            int lvBotMovableRange = (cBot.getHeight() + lvBottom.getDividerHeight()) * totalItemCount
                    - lvBottom.getDividerHeight() - lvBottom.getHeight();
            int lvBotPointer = (cBot.getHeight() + lvBottom.getDividerHeight()) * firstVisibleItem
                    - cBot.getTop();
            int lvTopPointer = (int)((float)(lvBotMovableRange - lvBotPointer)/lvBotMovableRange*lvTopMovableRange);
            int setposition = lvTopPointer / (cTop.getHeight() + lvTop.getDividerHeight());
            int sety = -lvTopPointer + setposition * (cTop.getHeight() + lvTop.getDividerHeight());
            timestampScroll = System.currentTimeMillis();
            lvTop.setSelectionFromTop(setposition, sety);
            lvBottom.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timestampScroll > (SCROLL_DELAY - 10)) fInBottomScrollListener = false;
                }
            }, SCROLL_DELAY);
        }
    }
};
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @i_A_mok.  That worked better. However, it still creeps if the 2 listviews are not the exact same height.  I'm defining the listview heights based on a weight value as I can't predict their height due to device variances, so I can't guarantee that they will each be the exact same height.  I may have to disable scrolling on one of the lists and let the other be the master.

Comment: Added a new answer that works no matter the listviews' heights are same or not.

Comment: Thanks again, that helps a lot.  I do still see a continuous ListView requestLayout in the log that may be an issue though the UI is stable.

W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.ListView{9653f66 VFED..C.. ........ 21,502-779,837 #7f050006 app:id/listViewBottom} during second layout pass: posting in next frame
W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.ListView{d5c2c8e VFED..C.. .F....I. 21,21-779,354 #7f050007 app:id/listViewTop} during layout: running second layout pass

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  The last update works great !!